# Why can't I save a file on my desktop?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, permissions, uac

Okay, I'm having issues that I haven't had before. I'm trying to save a file from Mozilla Firefox onto my desktop, but I get the error "You don't have permission to save in this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission." Now, I'm the only user on this PC, have administrator rights, am running Mozilla Firefox as administrator, I don't even have an anti-virus installed, it's a rather small file. I've tried lowering UAC, didn't work, I've tried in other folders, doesn't work, I've tried looking at the permissions tab for the desktop itself, everything is allowed (apart from the "special permissions" which I can't allow at all, for anyone). This doesn't happen all the time, only sometimes. The file I'm trying to download is a trimmed audio file from mp3cut.net, something I've done tons of times.I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Screenshots: http://prntscr.com/bz5ao0 http://prntscr.com/bz5bf0

Comment: well, I would have said look at the permissions, but, it seems you have done that... If no one else comes back with an answer, feel free to go to https://support.ezpcltd.com and install, I have 5 minutes to kill and happy to try to help, I can then write about the solution below after.

Comment: The error indicates your not trying to save to the desktop but the Mozilla program file folder which is odd

Comment: @Ramhound it's showing that because I didn't check where I was saving when I wanted to get the error again for the screenshot. But it's the same when I try to save to desktop, or anywhere else for that matter. http://prntscr.com/bz79jt The updated screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Answer - take two:

I think I see the issue thanks to your last screen shot.  If you look at the bottom of the dialog, you will se this warning message:
"warning: this file may be an executable program or contain malicious content, use caution before saving or opening"
The two ways I can think of fixing this is to rename the file entirely before you save it to lets say "abc.mp3".  As your file has period in it probably provoking that message.
That fix may not work, but I suspect its why you are only experiencing it on some files as other file names probably don't have another period in them.
The only other thing I can think of is disabling UAC, or disabling windows defender as its turned on by default.  Let me know!

------ old answer below-----

As ramhound indicated in the comments, Mozilla's firefox download location is not set to your desktop.  Rather, it is set to the path in program files\mozilla...

In order to remedy this, it is very easy.  I pulled this from Mozilla's website:
Click the menu button and choose Options.
Select General panel.
In the Downloads section, select Save files to.
To select a download location, click Browse.... Choose a different folder to try saving files.
Close the about:preferences page. Any changes you've made will automatically be saved.

Also, be careful with the symbols in the filename.  The screenshot you attached had parenthesis, hyphens, extra periods, all which are fine for normal file names; however, you may get some mp3 files that have illegal characters that aren't allowed in file names. This will cause saving issues as well if Mozilla isn't clever enough to strip that out.

Comment: Sadly, your method doesn't work. My default folder is already set to Downloads, but this isn't that type of download. Here is what I'm talking about http://prntscr.com/bz79jt It asks me to select a location, but no matter where I select, I get the same thing. The reason it showed to to the Mozilla folder is because I was in a hurry to get the same error to paste here, so I didn't check where I was saving. I get the same error, as you can see, when I try to save it to desktop.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it fixes your issue.

Comment: @WaidJohnson - You should edit your answer so its a single coherent thought.